# Are there any WordPress plugins that are the same as the Stack Overflow commenting system?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, markdown

Are there any WordPress plugins that are the same as the Stack Overflow commenting system? At first I thought about using the same engine that stackoverflow.com uses.  But i am not sure what CMS or engine the backend is running.  Hence I thought I could use WordPress and a commenting system like stackoverflow.

Comment: I'd ask on wordpress.stackexchange.com , might have better luck there

Comment: "The same" in what ways?

Comment: StackExchange runs its own proprietary platform written in ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: @Slaks Hmm, cool.  I thought it is running in PHP.  Good work Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, here you go: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qa/

FTA: "Q&A allows any WordPress site to have a fully featured questions and answers section - just like StackOverflow, Yahoo Answers, Quora and more...except better :)"

That is the lite version, they also offer a paid version with more features but that should give you a good idea of its capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for this perfect reply.  I am sure it is a genuine plugin.  because it is from WPMUDEV.

Comment: if this answer helped you please select it as "answered" thanks